# combine records based on overlapping time stamps using (snowflake) sql

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say I have for instance a dataset that consists of an ID and a start time and end time (ID, start_time, end_time):

- (A, 09, 11)
- (B, 10, 12)

I would need to remodel this dataset using sql code to the following format (combined_ID, start_time, end_time):

- (A, 09, 10)
- (A/B, 10, 11)
- (B, 11, 12)

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Snowflake is the name of  a product as is SQL Server.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a great place to get people to help you with issues you are running into, but not a great place to request somebody write code for you.  What have you tried so far?  My guess is you'll need to leverage a LAG() function to write an INSERT and UPDATE statement with a bunch of CASE statements.  This one isn't easy, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Mike Walton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12178980/mike-walton) that Stackoverflow is not the place to ask for free work,
but this was so quizzy I couldn't resist.

Your example only has two intervals, so I had to guess what to do with any number of intervals.
Here is my go:

```
WITH
  INPUT AS (SELECT * FROM VALUES ('A', 09, 11), ('B', 10, 12), ('C', 8, 11) T(ID, START_TIME, END_TIME)),
  SEGMENTS AS (
    SELECT
      SEGMENT_POINT SEGMENT_START,
      LEAD(SEGMENT_POINT, 1) OVER (ORDER BY SEGMENT_POINT) SEGMENT_END
    FROM (SELECT START_TIME SEGMENT_POINT FROM INPUT UNION SELECT END_TIME FROM INPUT)
  )
SELECT * FROM INPUT
UNION
SELECT
  LISTAGG(ID, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID),
  SEGMENT_START,
  ANY_VALUE(SEGMENT_END)
FROM INPUT /* Intersect with SEGMENTS */
INNER JOIN SEGMENTS ON START_TIME < SEGMENT_END AND END_TIME > SEGMENT_START
GROUP BY SEGMENT_START HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

With just A and B the query will output what you've listed above.  Adding (C, 8, 11) will output:

```
ID     START_TIME   END_TIME
C               8         11
A               9         11
A/C             9         10
A/B/C          10         11
B              10         12
```